# Show specific fields in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
                    echo "<table>";
                    for ($x=0; $x<=count
                    ($arr['chart_data']); $x++) {
                      echo "<tr>\n"; 
                    foreach($arr['chart_data'][$x] as $key=>$val)
                    {


                     echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>". $val . "</td>\n"; 



                    }  
                      echo "</tr>\n";
                    }

                   echo "</table>\n";
```

[image]

I want to show only the first 4 fields in the table. I am decoding a multidimensional array in php. I

Comment: x<=3; will result in steps 0,1,2,3

Comment: Well i solved 2 questions myself i am just new to php so taking me time sorry

Comment: @Gautam3164 That didn't solve my issue

Comment: You could try googleing stuff first.

Comment: @vini Set a variable (`$i`) to 1. Then run through your loop. After each iteration, add 1 to `$i`. If `$i` is more than `4` then `break;` out of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach($arr['chart_data'][$x] as $key=>$val) {
    if($cnt++ < 4) {
        echo "<td align='center;' style='color:white;'>". $val . "</td>\n"; 
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A slightly late response, but you should `break` out of the loop when you don't want to go any further, as an array with a million entries would loop through a million iterations (rather than 4).

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks for the suggestion.I just added it.I just thought that she has only 13-14 columns.Anyway thanks again

Comment: She might do, but remember that the most valueable answers are the ones that give a *generic* answer to help thousands of people rather than a single person. :-)